# not able to run MapReduce kmeans code

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, k-means

As i am beginner in map-reduce, I am trying to run this kmeans code.

https://github.com/thomasjungblut/thomasjungblut-common/tree/master/src/de/jungblut/clustering/mapreduce

I am using Eclipse Luna.
This code has so many other dependencies. I even tried with those file in eclipse, but plenty of dependency errors.

Please somebody help, how to execute this code in eclipse.
what are all the other files i need to check and download.

Comment: You're referring to Maven project, so make sure you know how to use Maven. Clone with git the whole project and import it in Eclipse as Maven project.

Comment: Maybe I should go and pull that out of my repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the code into a different repository.

You can now find it here:

https://github.com/thomasjungblut/mapreduce-kmeans

Please follow the build instructions and let me know if you find any errors.